# Looking for canonical problems or seminal work it the intersection of constraint programming and statistics

Tags: references, optimization, combinatorics, numerics, linear-programming

I'm interested in exploring the area (if it exists) at the intersection of constraint programming and statistics. My primary interest is on problems that require a combination of both statistical and constraint programming approaches to lead to a solution. As a commenter has pointed out that some statistical learning algorithms may take advantage of constraint programming such as support vector machines and vice-a-versa -- I guess these do qualify but are really low on my priority list. Thus for example:

1. Understanding the statistical properties of the temperature on a metal plate where the temperature distribution was computed by solving a finite element problem would amount to something that I'm looking for.
2. The algorithmic implementation of a support vector machine that uses a flavor of constraint programming is not what I'm looking for.

By constraint programming I mean:

1. Linear Programming
2. Mixed Integer Programming
3. Combinatorial Optimization
4. And, the like

I've done some preliminary digging on scholar.google.com and have found some papers but I've been unable to find what I would consider seminal sources on this area.

Question:

1. Does this area even exists as an established topic of research?
2. Could you point me to seminal resources on this subject.

Comment: do you mean in terms of algorithm implementations ( eg support vector machine uses quadratic programming, compressed sensing  ) or statistical problem definitions ?

Comment: Opps, how did I forget that ... thanks for pointing that out -- I was thinking more of problems that need to solved using statistical and constraint programming approaches -- let me edit the question based on your comment. Thanks again.

Comment: May be http://www.amazon.com/Restricted-Statistical-Inference-Probability-Statistics/dp/0471917877 ?

Comment: Quantile regression?